What do you call it when a blast furnace gets blocked and fills up with magma?
I read about blast furnaces in French and I can't find what some concepts are called in English. I know nothing about metallurgy, I'm just interested.
I read that one of the worst things that can happen to a blast furnace is that it get blocked by material at the bottom and fill up until basically needing to be dismantled.
Is there a name for this incident? And, I am specifically curious to know if there's a jargon term for the material building up inside the furnace.
Here's the relevant part of the French Wikipedia article on blast furnaces, translated to English:

A feared but rare incident is the "blockage" of the blast furnace. [...] A blockage at the bottom means that the molten material cannot be evacuated. The most frequent cause is a cold blast furnace due to accidental ingress of water or a heat deficit caused by the wind or coke, with excess heat leading to the same result. This rare and dreaded incident meant that the plant had to be shut down, perhaps permanently:
"If the engineer doesn't hurry up, it will be too late, and the furnace, filled with an immense magma, a wolf [French: loup], will have no choice but to stop; it will even have to be demolished in large part and long and costly work will have to be done to remove the ferrous, resistant mass that encumbers it from top to bottom and a large part of which only gives way willingly to the force of gunpowder... " — J. Garnier, Le Fer


have you googled blast furnace blockage?

In English, magma tends to be a geological term, rather a metallurgical term. From what I recall, and more knowledgeable people can correct me, what you are calling magma, metallurgists call molten material.

@jsotola Thank you. The term didn't appear so clearly in AI answers or at all on the WP article.

@Fred Right, just used the word from that quote as is, may have been figurative in French too.
